# Test classes with Developer Console

Tags: unit-test, class, developer-console

Is there any way of solving this bug? Basically, whenever I try to run a test (Username > Developer Console) I can run the tests and all but when I get to the part where I want to check the red & blue highlights, it simply doesn't show these and my allTests seperator goes down to 0%.

This is quite annoying and I can't test my classes through eclipse since it takes wayyyyyy too too long each time I run the tests, not to mention it is visually way more complex.

Best regards.

Comment: Shot in the dark - try clear all existing test results first (Setup->Develop->Apex Test Execution->View History->Clear Test Results), and then run your tests.  I have found that sometimes this fixes test result weirdness.  If this works i'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to work, at least for now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try clearing all existing test results first (Setup->Develop->Apex Test Execution->View History->Clear Test Results), and then run your tests. I have found that sometimes this fixes test result weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue in a sandbox on the Spring '14 release. I'm not entirely sure what fixed it, because I tried a lot of different things.

From within the **Developer Console**:

- Cleared the Test Data (Test > Clear Test Data)
- Cleared the Log Panel (Debug > Clear > Log Panel)
- Edited the Test Class (just added a comment and saved)

From the **Salesforce interface**:

- Recompiled all classes (Setup > Build > Develop > Apex Classes > Compile All Classes link)
- Double checked that all of the Test Data was Cleared (Setup > Build > Develop > Apex Test Execution > View Test History link > Clear Test Data button)

Then I ran the Test again (Developer Console > Test > New Run > Selected Test Class > Run), and everything seemed to work normally, and the red/blue highlighting showed up.